# Update Excel cells with a textbox via MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I started to learn programming again yesterday. As an assignment i made an API where it is possible to create Excel files, where it is possible to fill in a textbox and the text from this textbox will fill a cell in excel. Here is what i made for the assignment to create a excel file(The question comes after the code).

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult DownloadExcel(string field, int id = 0)
    {
        var bla = field;
        List<Record> obj = new List<Record>();
        obj = RecordInfo(field);
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.Append("<table border=`" + "1px" + "`b>");
        str.Append("<tr>");
        str.Append("<td><b><font face=Arial Narrow size=3>Fieldname</font></b></td>");
        str.Append("</tr>");
        foreach (Record val in obj)
        {
            str.Append("<tr>");
            str.Append("<td><font face=Arial Narrow size=" + "14px" + ">" + val.Fieldname.ToString() + "</font></td>");
            str.Append("</tr>");
        }
        str.Append("</table>");
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Information" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + ".xls");
        this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        byte[] temp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str.ToString());
        return File(temp, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    }

    public List<Record> RecordInfo(string fieldname = "test")
    {
        List<Record> recordobj = new List<Record>();
        recordobj.Add(new Record { Fieldname = fieldname });
        return recordobj;
    }
}
```

Now my question is. Is it possible to modify fields in Excel via C# and is it possible to modify a specific cell with a textbox and that the data will be changed on click (like for example, I want to adjust cell D7 from 1 to 2, so I go to my form and fill in 2 in the textbox and press submit and the specific cell will show the new number when i open Excel). I searched but couldn't find the answer. A link to how it can be made is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see i forgot to mention it's about a existing Excel sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late, but I answered my own question some time ago.
For the ones who are interested, here is the code for how I fixed my problem.

```
public class ExcelModel
{
    Application excelApp;

    string newValue;

    public ExcelModel(string newValue)
    {
        excelApp = new Application();
        this.newValue = newValue;
    }

    public void openExcelSheet(string fileName)
    {
        Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.get_Item(2);

        double oldValue = sheet.get_Range("D6").get_Value();



        sheet.Cells[6, 4] = newValue;

        workbook.SaveAs("\\Users\\user1\\Downloads\\text3.xlsx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        workbook.Close();
        excelApp.Visible = true;
        Workbook newWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("\\Users\\user1\\Downloads\\text3.xlsx");
    }

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult UpdateExcel(string field, int id = 0)
    {
        ExcelModel model = new ExcelModel(field);
        string file = "\\Users\\user1\\Downloads\\Testdocument.xlsx";
        model.openExcelSheet(file);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");


    }

    public List<Record> RecordInfo(string fieldname = "test")
    {
        List<Record> Recordobj = new List<Record>();
        Recordobj.Add(new Record { Fieldname = fieldname });
        return Recordobj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you switch to another approach and use a "grown-up" library for the excel file creation. EPPlus is free, offers great features and is very easy to use.

Have a look at the examples: http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that next time I create excel files. But does EPPlus also works on existing Excel files where I want to change a certain cell via a webpage with textbox + submit